# Husimi $Q$-function of Infinite Square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-optics, phase-space

Eigen-Wavefunction of infinite square well is
$$\psi(x)=\sqrt{2/l}\sin(n\pi x/l).$$ I want to write [Husimi $Q$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation) for infinite square well. General expression of Q function is $$Q=(1/2)\pi \langle \alpha|\rho|\alpha\rangle.$$ But I can’t use it for infinite square well as coherent states are written in term of superposition of eigenstates of harmonic oscillator. Also I don't want to solve Wigner function of infinite square well first and then find Q-function. I need to find Q-function directly. How could we find Q-function generally?

Comment: Are you comfortable with $ \langle x | \alpha\rangle=  {e^{-\frac{(x-\sqrt{2}\Re(\alpha))^2}{2} +ix \sqrt{2} \Im (\alpha)}}  /  {\pi^{1/4}}  $ ?

Comment: @CosmasZachos: if you would have decided to use \exp instead of e^, then perhaps I would have been able to read what you wrote. :-) Perhaps next time?

Comment: $\langle x | \alpha\rangle= \exp ({-\frac{(x-\sqrt{2}\Re(\alpha))^2}{2} +ix \sqrt{2} \Im (\alpha)} ) ~/   {\pi^{1/4}}       $ .