# Is there any way to write eigenstates of infinite square well in terms of eigenstates of harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I wanted to find Husimi Q function using expression $Q= \langle \alpha|\rho|\alpha \rangle$, where $|\alpha \rangle $ is coherent states of harmonic oscillator. I want to consider system $\rho=|u_n\rangle\langle u_n|$ for infinite square well. I wonder how I could take inner product of $\langle n|u_n \rangle$, where $|n \rangle$ is eigenstates of harmonic oscillator and $|u_n \rangle$ is eigen state of infinite square well. Is there any way to write eigenstates of infinite square well in terms of eigenstates of harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Trying in Mathematica, that inner product can be done in terms of Erf.

Comment: Hint: it is much easier to find the Wigner function for the square well, and then use standard Weierstrass transform conversion formulas   from the Wigner function to the Husimi... [equation 155 here](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf).  The freaky overlap integrals you are asking for might or might not be available in Schleich's book...

Comment: For the Wigner function, see [Belloni, Doncheski, Robinett, 2004](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1767100). [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/730174/husimi-q-function-of-infinite-square-well).